# Is it better to use the collapse clause

Tags: c++11, openmp

I am never sure which possibility I should choose to parallelize nested for loops.

For example I have the following code snippet:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
for(int b=0; b<bSize; b++)
    for(int n=0; n<N; n++) o[n + b*N] = b[n];


#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) schedule(static)
for(int b=0; b<bSize; b++)
    for(int n=0; n<N; n++) o[n + b*N] = b[n];
```

In the first snippet I use `parallel for` (with `schedule(static)` because of the first touch policy). In some codes I saw people use mostly the collapse-clausel to parallize nested for loops in other codes it is never used instead the nested for loops are parallelized with a simple `parallel for`. Is this more a habit or is there a difference between the two versions? Is there a reason some people never use `collapse(n)`?

Comment: As the ideal situation is to achieve simd optimization in the inner loop, it's usual better to avoid including the inner loop in a collapse.  Certain compilers even look for opportunities to include more than the innermost loop in simd optimization.  Parallel collapse might be expected to be of use when there is a remainder when dividing the outer loop count by the number of threads which would produce work imbalance.  I'm sure various aspects of this were discussed previously here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with everything in HPC, the answer is "It depends..."

Here it will depend on

1. How big your machine is and how big "bSize", and "N" are
2. What the content of the inner loop is

For static scheduling of iterations which all run in the same amount of time, unless you can guarantee that number of iterations being work-shared divides by the number of threads, you need to ensure that the number of available iterations is ~10x the number of threads  to guarantee 90% efficiency because of potential imbalance. Therefore if you have a 16 core machine you want >160 iterations. If "bSize" is small, then using collapse to generate more available parallelism will help performance. (In the worst case, imagine that "bSize" is smaller than the number of threads!)

On the other hand, as @tim18 is pointing out, if you can vectorize the inner loop while still maintaining enough parallelism that may be a better thing to do.

On the third hand, there is nothing to stop you doing both :-

```
#pragma omp for simd collapse(2)
for(int b=0; b<bSize; b++)
    for(int n=0; n<N; n++) o[n + b*N] = b[n];
```

If your inner loop really is this small (and vectorizable) then you certainly want to vectorize it, since, unlike parallelism, vectorization can reduce the total CPU time you use, rather than just moving it between cores.

Comment: I don't understand why you would be overly concerned about OpenMP prohibiting vectorization. There doesn't seem to be an inherent issue with that. A [quick check](https://godbolt.org/z/_H-3vQ) confirms that OpenMP loops can be vectorized without any other help. Of course, always measure & confirm still applies but preemptively trying to help the compiler here instead of giving the compiler the best possible information seems like a bad approach, especially for a beginner.